# Strange behavior when animating UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate a `UITextField` but I've been caught by a annoying and strange problem. My animation has the following sequence:

[image: first state]

In first state the application has the `UITextField`, the camera `UIButton` and the cancel `UIButton` after the camera button that is not been showed because it is been positioned out of the limits of the application. Actually my application has 320 of width and the cancel button origin is (350,7)

[image: second state]

In second state, when user touches on `UITextField`, the camera button alpha channel is set to 0 and the origin of cancel button is set to (247,7).

[image: final state]

The final state is the same as first state after user touched on Return button of keyboard or in cancel button.

During process the UITextField width and the cancel button origin in x axis are animated.

My code is:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  barcodeSearchButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  cancelButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

   CGFloat cancelButtonXOffset = CGRectGetMaxX(barcodeSearchButton.frame) - cancelButton.frame.size.width;
   CGFloat searchFieldWidth = searchField.frame.size.width - cancelButton.frame.size.width + barcodeSearchButton.frame.size.width;
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
         animations:^{
             searchField.frame = CGRectMake(searchField.frame.origin.x, searchField.frame.origin.y, searchFieldWidth, searchField.frame.size.height);
             cancelButton.alpha = 1.0;                
             cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(cancelButtonXOffset, cancelButton.frame.origin.y, cancelButton.frame.size.width,cancelButton.frame.size.height);

             barcodeSearchButton.alpha = 0.0;

         }
         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             barcodeSearchButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
             cancelButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
         }];    
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  barcodeSearchButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  cancelButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     searchField.frame = CGRectMake(searchField.frame.origin.x, searchField.frame.origin.y, searchFieldStartWidth, searchField.frame.size.height);
                     cancelButton.alpha = 0.0;
                     cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(cancelButtonStartX, cancelButton.frame.origin.y, cancelButton.frame.size.width,cancelButton.frame.size.height);
                     barcodeSearchButton.alpha = 1.0;                
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     barcodeSearchButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                     cancelButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                 }];        
}
```

When the animation is executed until the final state ONLY for the first time, which means, user touched on UITextField, WROTE DOWN (this part is important) some text on field and after that the user touched on keyboard return button the problem appears. The problem is that the typed text in UITextField is animated when the width of UITextField is animated too.

The animation behaves like bellow:

1. The `UITextField` stretches back to its initial value.
2. Cancel button backs to its initial origin
3. Camera button is set to 1.0
4. The typed text flies from the top-left corner of `UITextField` and it lands into `UITextfield` to the position the it should not have gone.

The problem is that the step 4 should not happen and the problem is it happens only one time. If a start the process again (touch on uitextfield, type some text, touch on return key) the step 4 does not happen.

I spend a day long trying to solve this problem but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for answers of everyone but I've found the solution some time ago. The correct way to start an animation in a `UITextField`, depending on the keyboard state, is overriding the methods `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and `textFieldShouldEndEditing`.

My first attempt I was overriding `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` to create the animations. I don't know the reason to the animations work in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and `textFieldShouldEndEditing` but not in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing`. But it just works.

My revised code version:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    CGFloat cancelButtonXOffset = CGRectGetMaxX(barcodeSearchButton.frame) -    cancelButton.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat searchFieldWidth = searchField.frame.size.width - cancelButton.frame.size.width + barcodeSearchButton.frame.size.width;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
         animations:^{
             searchField.frame = CGRectMake(searchField.frame.origin.x, searchField.frame.origin.y, searchFieldWidth, searchField.frame.size.height);
             cancelButton.alpha = 1.0;                
             cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(cancelButtonXOffset, cancelButton.frame.origin.y, cancelButton.frame.size.width,cancelButton.frame.size.height);

             barcodeSearchButton.alpha = 0.0;

         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             searchField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
         }]; 
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
         animations:^{
             searchField.frame = CGRectMake(searchField.frame.origin.x, searchField.frame.origin.y, searchFieldStartWidth, searchField.frame.size.height);
             cancelButton.alpha = 0.0;
             cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(cancelButtonStartX, cancelButton.frame.origin.y, cancelButton.frame.size.width,cancelButton.frame.size.height);
             barcodeSearchButton.alpha = 1.0;                
         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             searchField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever;
         }];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: This works well. Fixes a different issue I had related to animating UITextFields when using UIControlEventEditingDidEnd. Switched to this set up and the animations were fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Set some placeholder text on the search field, 
_searchField.text = @"placeholder"

and also set 
_searchField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;

Or you can just clear out the value if it's equal to your placeholder text
on textDidBeginEditing

Comment: Also, using text instead of the placeholder text property may mess with your colors, so you will have to fix that up as well.

Answer (score 0):

{edited to improve the fix}
I have this exact same problem, and some further details as well as a small hack that is indeed fixing it for me.

So first the further details:

1. The problem only occurs the first time the frame animation expands
   the `UITextField` and there is entered text in the field. If the
   `UITextField` is edited again, and the same animations happen again,
   the problem does not happen.
2. `searchField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;` does not clear the problem.
3. I've been using placeholder text the entire time the problem has
   been observed.  It has no effect on the results.
4. Changing the text property for 1 frame does have the effect of clearing the problem.

Here is what I am doing to fix it:

In my `viewDidLoad` I am setting the text property to a single space, then dispatching once an assignment to an empty string.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    searchField.text = @" ";
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        searchField.text = @"";
    });
}
```

Then in my methods that shrink and expand the `UITextField`, as well as move a cancel button on-screen, I check if this is an instantaneous animation and set the duration to 0.0f.

```
- (void)showCancelButton {
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0.3f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{ 
        CGPoint buttonOrigin = cancelButton.frame.origin;
        CGSize buttonSize = cancelButton.frame.size;
        CGFloat buttonTravelDist = buttonSize.width + 10.0f;
        CGPoint onscreenPos = CGPointMake(buttonOrigin.x - buttonTravelDist, buttonOrigin.y);

        cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(onscreenPos.x, onscreenPos.y, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);

        CGPoint fieldOrigin = searchField.frame.origin;
        CGSize fieldSize = searchField.frame.size;

        searchField.frame = CGRectMake(fieldOrigin.x, fieldOrigin.y, fieldSize.width - buttonTravelDist, fieldSize.height);
    }];
}

- (void)hideCancelButton {
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0.3f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{ 
        CGPoint buttonOrigin = cancelButton.frame.origin;
        CGSize buttonSize = cancelButton.frame.size;
        CGFloat buttonTravelDist = buttonSize.width + 10.0f;
        CGPoint onscreenPos = CGPointMake(buttonOrigin.x + buttonTravelDist, buttonOrigin.y);

        cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(onscreenPos.x, onscreenPos.y, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);

        CGPoint fieldOrigin = searchField.frame.origin;
        CGSize fieldSize = searchField.frame.size;

        searchField.frame = CGRectMake(fieldOrigin.x, fieldOrigin.y, fieldSize.width + buttonTravelDist, fieldSize.height);
    }];
}
```

This has completely fixed the situation for me.